# iOS Localization of bundle display name for en-GB and en-US

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

We are developing an app for football (Soccer). The app is only supporting English, but football has different meaning around the world. I.e in US / Australia / Japan / New Zealand they use soccer instead of football. We want to determine the display name based on the language selected on the device.

We want to achieve that the display name in US / Australia / Japan / New Zealand is "Soccer" and in the rest of the world it should be "Football".

### Implementation

We thought after reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1828/_index.html) documentation from Apple, that we could have a fallback language mechanism. So we implemented following.

We created a file called `InfoPlist.strings` that supports following:

```
en-GB
en-US
en-AU
en-NZ
ja
```

The InfoPlist.strings files is constructed like so:

#### en-GB

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Football";
CFBundleName = "Football";
```

#### en-[US / AU / NZ] / ja

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Soccer";
CFBundleName = "Soccer";
```

#### Project structure

[image]

Other than this we specified the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` in the Info.plist to `en-GB` / `United Kingdom`.

We have also tried to add following to the Info.plist but with no luck:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```

```
<key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
<true/>
```

When you are selecting one of the supported languages as preferred language on the device it works fine. But when you choose a not supported language (i.e. German) it falls back to the `en-US` localization. Can you help us understand that?

In theory the OS looks up the preferred language (in this case German), and finds out that it is not supported. After that, if it the has the base language (without a dialect) supported it will use that one. It is also not available in this case. Then it end up at the last step:

> If none of the user’s preferred languages are supported by your app, iOS chooses the language matching your app's development region (`CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`).

In our case we have `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` defined to `en-GB` / `United Kingdom`.

We will expect to see "Football" as the display name, but we see "Soccer" (`en-US` localization). We don't understand.

Hope you can help us - thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you edit your post and add a screenshot of the project hierarchy (focused on the Info,plist) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing same issue in ios 14, seems a bug, whenever there is definicion for a specific locale en-XX the general one is never used. Instead, the alphabetical order is used for the specific ones.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663628

In order to workaround this, there is an specific language en-001, I add that to the project and fill the values with the default ones. So it always solve the not defined specific with en-001 definition.

Comment: Hello how you resolved this issue? Could you please explain?

Comment: Hi @AKS, I added en-001 support in the app and move there the en translations, that way, by default, any non existent en-xx is translated into the default en-001